# form tag submission in HTML vs document.getElementById("form1").submit() in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hey so I am currently learning how to code in JS and I have a question;
why do I need to use document.getElementById("form1").submit() when I can just submit a form and data within it by adding a submit button in html and keeping it within a form tag? Sorry if this sounds like a completely noob question but I am trying to learn to here :) 
p.s also googled this query and did my research but could not really find a definitive answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't NEED to, but you can use document.getElementById("form1").submit() if you want to trigger the submit event of the form (which is EXACTLY the same as clicking the HTML submit button) programmatically.

If you for example have another even, like, a custom button outside the form that you want to act as the submit button for the form, then you can use the document.getElementById("form1").submit() in order to trigger the submit of the form from a button that doesn't have to be inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use html submit on an `<input>` tag which comes with default CSS stylings. If you want to do something different with your submit button, like have it be an image or a link, you can use any CSS stylings you want, and then programmatically call submit()